# MATLAB GUI not generating the callback function for a button

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am developing a GUI on MATLAB and for some unknown reason I am unable to get the callback function of any new button I am adding.

I remember when putting in a new button I should just put the button on the GUI and press save, the function is generated automatically.

For some reason it is not doing that anymore!
This below does not show up anymore:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
display('Goodbye');
close(gcf);
```

Also, if I right click on a button and go to the callback function, only the property inspector is opened.

I dont know whats going on it can be something really stupid that I am missing but any help would be great!

Thanks;

Comment: Any code you have of the gui, or some dummy version to see how you the gui code looks like would be good.

Comment: What if you "save as" under a different name and try again? Something similar already occurred to me a while ago and it did the trick.

Comment: If you are using GUIDE, the callback should be generated when double-clicking on it (within GUIDE)!

Answer (score 0):

Right click the button on GUI, select "call back", only then the function is created in the m file.